# Secrets management during kafka-connector startup

Tags: apache-kafka-connect

I am using Kafka connector as source-connector. The documentation provides a way to manage [credentials in filesystem and apply them not as plain texts while creating connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/security.html#externalizing-secrets) using the REST API.

This works if the kafka-connector is up and running and we try to create a new connector(instance).

But during startup of the Kafka Connect worker itself if we need to pass some credentials, say SSL cert passwords, in distributed properties file. 
Is that possible with the FileConfigProvider provided by kafka-connect or by externalizing configProvider?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the same approach as for externalised configuration in connector configuration itself.

1. In the worker configuration, define the config provider. For a file provider it looks like this:

   ```
   config.providers=file
   config.providers.file.class=org.apache.kafka.common.config.provider.FileConfigProvider
   ```
2. For the file provider, create a file (e.g. `/data/connect_external.properties`) with the key/value configuration items:

   ```
   SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=nevergonnagiveyouup
   GROUP_ID=my_connect_group
   ```
3. In the worker configuration specify the configuration items you'd like to source from the configuration provider, just the same you would for a connector itself. For example, to override the group id and the SSL key store password using the config specified in the sample file above:

   ```
   group.id=${file:/data/connect_external.properties:GROUP_ID}
   ssl.keystore.password=${file:/data/connect_external.properties:SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD}
   ```

When the Kafka Connect worker launches you'll see it uses the new values. Since the SSL credentials are already masked you just see that it's a hidden value.

```
    [2020-06-16 13:03:09,721] INFO DistributedConfig values:
    …
    group.id = my_connect_group
    ssl.keystore.password = [hidden]
```

Ref: https://rmoff.net/2019/05/24/putting-kafka-connect-passwords-in-a-separate-file-/-externalising-secrets/